# Displaying a <td> background image responsively using VML

Tags: outlook, html-email, vml

This is for a new HTML Outlook signature I'm trying to create. I have a single row HTML table that has several s. The table is set to display at the full width of its container. And the single row currently contains two s (this may change later).

These two columns don't contain text just background images. These background images must fill the entire space of the .

So this is what I've already tried

**The image is set to display at the full width of the td but It renders only in a small space.** *The Image is 460 px wide.*

[image]

````
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

   <body>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td background="Testing_files/receptionist.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" valign="top" width="50%">

       <!--[if gte mso 9]>
         <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
         <v:fill type="frame" src="Testing_files/receptionist.png" color="#7bceeb" />

       <![endif]-->

      <div>
     </div>

  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->

</td>
<td>
``` The second column
</td>
````

These two columns don't contain text just background images. These background images must fill the entire space of the . What am I doing wrong? any help would be greatly appreciated since I'm new to VML.

Comment: VML needs a fixed height and width to take up the whole space. When sent thru an ESP the image has to be uploaded, linked (sometimes manually as some ESP's don't recognize the code), sent and tested in Outlook. Now that's VML. As for signature, try to stay away from background images. It causes nightmares while testing. If you want to see renderings try Litmus to see how signatures will render but it has to be really basic.

Comment: @syfer Thanks mate. Why doesn't setting mso-width-percent:1000 help?

Comment: The 1000 is meant to be percent and used as a background of the whole page. If you are doing it on a specific block which has a required size, stick to width and height on VML. This link will help: https://backgrounds.cm/